# Как проверить содержание подменю?

Tags: javascript, menu

Подскажите, как проверить есть ли у меню подменю? Моя задумка простая: если у элемента `li` внутри есть элемент `ul`, значит подменю содержится и родителю нужно задать класс.

```
<nav class="header__nav">
      <ul class="header__menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Catalog</a>
          <ul class="header__submenu">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
          <ul class="header__submenu">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Но как это реализовать на `js` никак не пойму. Вариант 1:

```
const menu = document.querySelector('.header__menu').children;
for (let item of menu) {
  if (item.contains("UL")) {
    console.log('hi');
  }
}
```

Тут получаю ошибку, что первый параметр `contains` не `Node`. Я не пойму, как передать 1 параметр в `contains` так, чтобы это был `Node`?

2 вариант:

```
for (let item of menu) {
  for (let i = 0; i < item.childNodes.length; i++) {
    if (item.childNodes[i] == 'LI') {
      console.log('hi');
    }
  }
}
```

Тоже не понятно как проверить)
Подскажите, как правильно делать данную проверку?

Comment: Насколько глубокая предполагается вложенность?

Comment: @UModeL 2-х уровневое меню. С одним уровнем вложенности

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `querySelectorAll` по полной. Просто отталкивайтесь от обратного - вместо перебора, ищите *сразу нужные* элементы, а после их родителей.

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('li > ul')].forEach(ul => {
  ul.parentElement.classList.add('red');
})
```

```css
.red { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<nav class="header__nav">
  <ul class="header__menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Catalog</a>
      <ul class="header__submenu">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
      <ul class="header__submenu">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

1 contains принимает node элемент а не тег потому и ошибка

2 нужно проверять на elem.childNodes[i].**tagName**

как алтернатива

```
const menu = document.querySelector('.header__menu').children;
  for(let key of menu){
    if((key.querySelector('ul'))){
      console.log(key)
    }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]